# Running amd64 apps on arm ubuntu

Tags: plasma, arm, emulation

I have just installed Ubuntu on my m1 mac as I gave into people saying that it was amazing and I have to say I love it, however, I really love opera but every time i try and install it doesn't work because it is for amd64 and I am trying to run it on arm so it doesn't work, is there any kind of emulator software available (like Rosetta) that would allow me to run these kinds of apps on arm Linux? Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Sorry no it would be putting gas in a diesel engine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any translation layer for x86 software on Ubuntu ARM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376366/is-there-any-translation-layer-for-x86-software-on-ubuntu-arm)

Answer (score 0):

No. You will need ARM versions of the software you want to install.
There is no Opera ARM version and Opera is the one that needs to provide it.