# issues installing packet tracer (ubuntu, parallels, M1 MacBook)

Tags: cisco, arm64, parallels

I am trying to install Cisco Packet Tracer in Ubuntu running in Parallels on an M1 MacBook Air.

So when I go to install the .deb file I get an error saying `Wrong architecture AMD64 run dpkg --add-architecture to add it and update afterwards`. I was running a program called app grid to unpack and install.

I have run that command in terminal but it doesn't work. I have also run the following in terminal:

```
parallels@ubuntu-linux-20-04-desktop:~$ sudo dpkg -i /home/parallels/Downloads/CiscoPacketTracer_811_Ubuntu_64bit.deb
dpkg: error processing archive /home/parallels/Downloads/CiscoPacketTracer_811_Ubuntu_64bit.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/parallels/Downloads/CiscoPacketTracer_811_Ubuntu_64bit.deb
```

SO I assume that I need a version that supports ARM, which is weird because packet tracer works fine in virtual Windows 11

Any ideas?

Comment: So... [Windows 11 ARM supports running AMD64 programs](https://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-states-x64-emulation-only-available-windows-11-arm-pcs). Ubuntu... doesn't by default. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1376366/1438484) for one way to do it that might work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any translation layer for x86 software on Ubuntu ARM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376366/is-there-any-translation-layer-for-x86-software-on-ubuntu-arm)